# Total number of incident report from atlassian status page

Tags: statuspage-api

Is there any way to get the report of total number incidents so far created in manage.statuspage.io.

Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the REST APIs specifically [Get a list of all incidents](https://doers.statuspage.io/api/v1/incidents/#list-all)? This might help you out.

Comment: I tried using below , but I am getting "null" as the output though the incidents were already created `curl -X GET https://manage/pages/**PAGEID**/incidents.json -H "Authorization: Basic **APIKEY**"`

Comment: I tried as `incidents` instead of `incidents.json` , Getting output in HTML  format.

But getting "null" as the response while trying to get the values in json format ( incidents.json)

Comment: found the way through the link you provided